# Cocos2D: CCLabelTTF won't preserve ending whitespace.

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, whitespace, spaces, preserve

I need to have a CCLabelTTF print spaces at the end of a string, but they won't.  I can log the string and clearly see that the spaces at the end are preserved by highlighting the log.

I've tried appending a decimal ascii non-breaking space, but it shows up as a different character. The font I'm using is Monaco.

Comment: Out of interest why did you need to do this?

Comment: CCLabelTTF class is not available in android?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Instead of appending @" " I appended the unicode value U+00A0 like this:

labelPieceObj = [labelPieceObj stringByAppendingString:@"\u00A0"];